# EXCEL If cell x is empty fill cell y with cell z

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If cell x from worksheet 1 is empty, fill cell y in worksheet 2 with cell z from worksheet 1

***If customer PO No (worksheet 1) is empty then use Quote No (worksheet 1) to fill Quote/PO No (worksheet 2)

[image: WORKSHEET1]

[image: WORKSHEET2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following formula in cell `Y` of `sheet 2`

```
=IF(Sheet1!B1="",Sheet1!B2,"")
```

`Sheet1 B1` is `X`

`Sheet1 B2` is `Z`

Comment: Thank you, I also needed to add that it should use Sheet!B1 if not empty but I think I worked that part out...

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK(Sheet!B1),Sheet!B2,Sheet!B1)